# A way to compare values when looping over time?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I’m trying to compare two values from certain points in time when looping over dates

```
import time

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

horse_url = "http://www.harness.org.au/racing/horse-search/?horseId=813476"with requests.Session() as s:
    try:
        webpage_response = s.get(horse_url)
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        webpage_response.status_code = "Connection refused"

    table = BeautifulSoup(
        webpage_response.content,
        "html.parser",
    ).find('table', class_='table table-hover small horsePerformance') 

Targetdate = “1 Jan 2021”

   For row in table.find_all(“tr”)[1:]:
        date = row.find(“td”, class_=“date”).find(“a”).getText()
        If time.strptime(date, “%d %b %Y) <= time.strptime(Targetdate, “%d %b %Y):
    Print(date)
```

Will print

26 Dec 2020
24 Nov 2020
10 Oct 2020
01 Oct 2020
...

I want to get days between top line and 2nd in for loop (so get days between 26 Dec and 24 Nov)

Tried this

```
If time.strptime(date, “%d %b %Y) <= time.strptime(Targetdate, “%d %b %Y):
    Dateprior = tr.find(“td”, class_=“date”.find_next(“td”, class_=“date”).get_text().strip()
    ...
```

However this seemingly starts from the bottom of the rows rather than the top row and next proceeding it.

Comment: Is there an url or html to go with this?

Comment: Is this some kind of a homework because this is *oddly* similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67054757/scrape-data-from-a-date-onwards/67055776). Even the link is the same. And the problem too!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [scrape data from a date onwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67054757/scrape-data-from-a-date-onwards)